# Number Theory Contest Math

Tags: number-theory, contest-math

Find the smallest positive integer $n$ such that $n^4 + (n + 1)^4$ is composite.
Find the sum of the first $5$ positive integers $n$ such that $n^2 - 1$ is the product of 3 distinct primes.

Answer to the first is $5$, and answer to the second is 104. Can anyone show me the solution process?

Comment: ...direct computation?

Comment: Preferably not, but I can understand if that is the process for the first.

Comment: For the second, you must have that one of $n+1$, $n-1$ is an odd prime and the other is the product of two odd primes, which narrows it down.

Comment: so 14 and 16 are solutions

Comment: and 20,22,and 32, cool

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the second one

$$n^2-1=(n-1)(n+1)$$

This is the product of three primes if and only if

- $n-1=1$ and $n+1$= product of three primes. (not possible)
- $n-1$ is prime and $n+1$= is the product of two primes.
- $n+1$ is prime and $n-1$= is the product of two primes.

Thus, for the first few primes, you need to test if $p \pm 2$ is the product of two primes. Note that in this case $n=p \pm 1$ depending on the choice of sign in the first one.

The first five primes for which this happens are $13, 17, 19, 23, 31$. The corresponding $5$ n's are....

Answer (score 7):

For the first one, it helps to know that if $a,b$ are relatively prime then
any prime factor of $a^4+b^4$ is either $2$ or congruent to $1 \bmod 8$.
(This happens to be in my first published paper $-$ admittedly this
"publication" was the proceedings of a local high-school Math Fair...
$-$ and can proved similarly to one proof of the corresponding $1 \bmod 4$
result for $a^2+b^2$, by finding an $8$th root of unity $a/b \bmod p$.)
Since $n$ and $n+1$ are relatively prime and of opposite parity,
this means you need only check divisibility by $17$, $41$, $73$, etc.
For $n < 5$, the value of $n^4 + (n+1)^4$ is small enough that
the only candidate composite number is $17^2 = 289$, which you can
exclude by direct computation or otherwise (e.g. Fermat proved
that there's no solution of $a^4+b^4=c^2$ in positive integers;
or, the only Pythagorean triangle with hypotenuse $17$ has sides
$8$ and $15$).  So $n=5$ is the first candidate, and the first
candidate prime factor actually divides $5^4 + 6^4 = 1921 = 17 \cdot 113$,
so we're done.

Comment: you are a genius Noam!

Comment: (To clarify:
I was certainly not the first to obtain the result about $p \mid a^4+b^4$,
which must be classical; I just remember it well because I happen to have
noticed it independently.)